# What would be the best way to draw these pyramids?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have tried to just use normal tikzpicture to draw these or 3D objects but it takes so long since I have to know all measurement to draw accurately. This is okay for 2D diagrams since I can use a 2D plane but not sure how to do this for 3D objects. Is there a more efficient way?

[image]
[image]

For example, I have done this with overleaf, which is not too hard.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: There are many ways are there, but one of the best is using `tikz`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `tikz-3dplot` package.
Without working out all the details, your first picture could then be achieved by using something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% Plot display orientation
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{115}

\definecolor{pyramidblue}{RGB}{19,131,183}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0,pyramidblue,fill opacity=0.5] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,thick,pyramidblue,dashed] (2,-2) -- (-2,-2) -- (-2,2);
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,thick,pyramidblue] (2,-2) -- (2,2) -- (-2,2);
        \draw[thick,pyramidblue,dashed](-2,-2,0) -- (-1,-1,3);
        \draw[thick,pyramidblue](2,-2,0) -- (1,-1,3);
        \draw[thick,pyramidblue](-2,2,0) -- (-1,1,3);
        \draw[thick,pyramidblue](2,2,0) -- (1,1,3);
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=3,thick,pyramidblue,fill,fill opacity=0.5] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: example 3D object]